# Pandas: delete rows based on the value of other row

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a pandas data frame with column names as 'ID', 'datetime', 'medication'. Now I am trying to eliminate all the morphine medication rows with respect to methadone medication given time.

For example:

ID-66531 received first methadone medication at time 2013-02-19 20:54. Since methadone and morphine, both are pain killers the effect of the medications are the same. So I am trying to eliminate morphine medication rows if methadone was given within 24hr period of morphine medication for each ID group. So for the ID-66531 if any morphine falls between the 24 hour time range of methadone given which is 2013-02-18 20:53 and 2013-02-19 20:54 in this case, I want to remove those record for each ID group

**Actual dataframe:**

```
64347   2012-02-15 19:24:00 morphine
64347   2012-02-15 22:54:00 morphine
64347   2012-02-16 05:50:00 morphine
64347   2012-02-16 12:47:00 oxyCODONE
64347   2012-10-20 05:03:00 morphine
64347   2012-10-21 15:10:00 morphine
64347   2012-10-21 19:06:00 morphine
64347   2012-11-16 16:00:00 morphine
64990   2012-09-21 07:10:00 oxyCODONE
64990   2012-09-21 16:45:00 fentaNYL
64990   2012-09-21 23:21:00 oxyCODONE
64990   2012-09-22 15:40:00 oxyCODONE
66531   2012-12-18 08:31:00 acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
66531   2012-12-18 17:44:00 acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
66531   2013-02-18 22:36:00 morphine
66531   2013-02-19 05:07:00 morphine
66531   2013-02-19 10:13:00 morphine
66531   2013-02-19 15:27:00 morphine
66531   2013-02-19 17:33:00 oxyCODONE
66531   2013-02-19 19:20:00 acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
66531   2013-02-19 20:54:00 methadone
66531   2013-02-20 06:46:00 methadone
66531   2013-02-20 13:21:00 methadone
66531   2013-02-20 22:18:00 methadone
```

**Expected data frame:**

```
64347   2012-02-15 19:24:00 morphine
64347   2012-02-15 22:54:00 morphine
64347   2012-02-16 05:50:00 morphine
64347   2012-02-16 12:47:00 oxyCODONE
64347   2012-10-20 05:03:00 morphine
64347   2012-10-21 15:10:00 morphine
64347   2012-10-21 19:06:00 morphine
64347   2012-11-16 16:00:00 morphine
64990   2012-09-21 07:10:00 oxyCODONE
64990   2012-09-21 16:45:00 fentaNYL
64990   2012-09-21 23:21:00 oxyCODONE
64990   2012-09-22 15:40:00 oxyCODONE
66531   2012-12-18 08:31:00 acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
66531   2012-12-18 17:44:00 acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
66531   2013-02-19 17:33:00 oxyCODONE
66531   2013-02-19 19:20:00 acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
66531   2013-02-19 20:54:00 methadone
66531   2013-02-20 06:46:00 methadone
66531   2013-02-20 13:21:00 methadone
66531   2013-02-20 22:18:00 methadone
```

**What I tried:**

I created a timediff column which gets the time difference of the between two records.

`df['timediff'] = df.sort_values(by= 'datetime').groupby('ID')['datetime'].diff()`

then I assigned 24 hours to a variable x

`x = '24:00:00'` and tried the following code to remove morphine

`df = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x : x.loc[~(x['Medication'] == 'morphine')<x]`

but this code removes the morphine records irrespective of the methadone medication given time.

I'd really appreciate if I can get some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('test.tsv', header=None, sep='\s+',
                     parse_dates = [['date', 'time']],
                     names=['patient_id', 'date', 'time','drug'])

to_drop = set()
for _, patient in df.groupby('patient_id'):
    meth_times = patient.loc[patient['drug'] == 'methadone']['date_time']
    morph_doses = patient.loc[patient['drug'] == 'morphine']
    for i, md in morph_doses.iterrows():
        for mt in meth_times:
            days_elapsed = (mt - md['date_time']).days
            if days_elapsed < 1:
                to_drop.add(i)
                break

df = df[~df.index.isin(to_drop)]
```

As with @ulmefors suggested answer, this is iterating repeatedly over each of the morphine/methadone rows, so it's somewhat inefficient, but unless you're working with a huge dataset it should get the job done quickly enough that this will be insignificant. (But unlike the other answer, it is only iterating multiple times within each patient's morphine/methadone doses rather than through all possible combinations of rows)

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> names = ['Id', 'Datetime', 'Drug']
>>> df = pd.read_csv('drugs.csv', names=names, parse_dates=['Datetime'])
>>> df

    Id      Datetime                Drug
0   66531   2012-12-18 08:31:00     acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
1   66531   2012-12-18 17:44:00     acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
2   66531   2013-02-18 22:36:00     morphine
3   66531   2013-02-19 05:07:00     morphine
4   66531   2013-02-19 10:13:00     morphine
5   66531   2013-02-19 15:27:00     morphine
6   66531   2013-02-19 17:33:00     oxyCODONE
7   66531   2013-02-19 19:20:00     acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
8   66531   2013-02-19 20:54:00     methadone
9   66531   2013-02-20 06:46:00     methadone
10  66531   2013-02-20 13:21:00     methadone
11  66531   2013-02-20 22:18:00     methadone
```

Then, loop through all the row combinations. It works, but is not the most effective solution. If your data set is very large you might want to consider a more elegant approach.

```py
drop_idx = set([])
for idx_early, row_early in df.iterrows():
    for idx_late, row_late in df.iterrows():
        if (row_early['Datetime'] + pd.DateOffset(hours=24) > row_late['Datetime'] and
            row_early['Datetime'] < row_late['Datetime'] and
            row_early['Drug'] == 'morphine' and
            row_late['Drug'] == 'methadone' and
            row_early['Id'] == row_late['Id']):
            drop_idx.add(idx_early)
```

Now, drop the identified rows and print result.

```py
>>> df.drop(index=drop_idx)

    Id      Datetime                Drug
0   66531   2012-12-18 08:31:00     acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
1   66531   2012-12-18 17:44:00     acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
6   66531   2013-02-19 17:33:00     oxyCODONE
7   66531   2013-02-19 19:20:00     acetaminophen-HYDROcodone
8   66531   2013-02-19 20:54:00     methadone
9   66531   2013-02-20 06:46:00     methadone
10  66531   2013-02-20 13:21:00     methadone
11  66531   2013-02-20 22:18:00     methadone
```

Comment: You forgot to `groupby('ID')`

Comment: @smci The row `row_early['Id'] == row_late['Id']` will make sure that only rows with same `Id` are considered. The code could potentially be neater and/or more performant with the `groupby`, but it will work fine without it.

Comment: @ulmefiors: Two O(N^2) nested loops `for idx_early, row_early in df.iterrows(): for idx_late, row_late in df.iterrows(): ...` and the gating condition `and row_early['Id'] == row_late['Id']):` is a pretty nasty and non-scaleable way to mimic `groupby('ID')`. Also, your code is assuming that all rows for a given `Id` occur in order, which seems risky.

Comment: @smci I 100% agree this is not scaleable for huge data sets. The current data set is unfortunately unknown. Perhaps it's only a few 1000s rows. The code is not assuming that rows occur in order since it is looping through **all** possible combinations. This is good because it works (I invite you to try), but obviously bad with regards to performance. A different solution would indeed be preferable for large data sets. Would you have a good idea for high performant code suitable for a larger data set?

Comment: What earthly reason do you have to not simply use `groupby('ID')`?